# ngx-charts - Horizontal Bar Charts bar thickness changes on data update

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I'm using Angular and ngx-charts to show some data that is pulled from the server. 

On first load, when the ngOnInit() method triggers the request to the server (getStats()), 
everything is loaded as it should: 
[image]

But when the *Get Data* button is clicked, and the same request is sent to the server(getStats()), the table is re-rendered like this: 
[image]

The bar lines get thinned out.

Html:

```
<div class="row shadow">
    <div class="col" style="height: 80vh; width: 100%;"> 
        <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal
            [scheme]="colorScheme"
            [results]="data"
            [gradient]="gradient"
            [xAxis]="showXAxis"
            [yAxis]="showYAxis"
            [legend]="showLegend"
            [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
            [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
            [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
            [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
            (select)="onSelect($event)">
        </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>                                
    </div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

````
    export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private adminService: AdminService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private formBulder: FormBuilder,
    private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef ) { }

    days = 7; // Days you want to subtract
    date = new Date();
    endMonth = this.date.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    endDay = this.date.getUTCDate();
    endyear = this.date.getUTCFullYear();
    endDate = this.endyear + '/' + this.endMonth + '/' + this.endDay;
    last = new Date(this.date.getTime() - (this.days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    startDay = this.last.getDate();
    startMonth= this.last.getMonth()+1;
    startYear = this.last.getFullYear();
    startDate = this.startYear + '/' + this.startMonth + '/' + this.startDay;

  statsSearchFrom = this.formBulder.group({
    startTime: [this.startDate, Validators.required],
    endTime: [this.endDate, Validators.required]
  });

  agents: User[];
  data: any[] = [];
  multi: any[];
  // view: any[] = [100%, 800];
  // bar chart options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Number of Tickets';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Agent';

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#263859', '#a7d129', '#21e6c1', '#278ea5', '#7045af', '#e14594', '#ed6363', '#3c6562']
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllAgents();
  }

  getStats() {
    const startTime = this.datePipe.transform(this.statsSearchFrom.controls['startTime'].value, 'ddMMyyyy');
    const endTime = this.datePipe.transform(this.statsSearchFrom.controls['endTime'].value, 'ddMMyyyy');
    this.adminService.getAgentStats(this.agents, startTime, endTime).subscribe(response => {
      this.agents = response;
      for (const agent of this.agents) {
        const point: any = {'name': agent.username, 'value': agent.nbOfClosedEmails};
        this.data.push(point);
      }
      this.data = [...this.data];
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error('Error while getting the statistics.')
    });
  }

  getAllAgents() {
    this.adminService.getAllAgents().subscribe(response => {
      this.agents = response;
      this.agents = [...this.agents];
      this.getStats();
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error('Error while getting the agents.');
      console.error(error);
    });
  }```
````

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. I get variable number of bars from API every some time. If there are only 2 bars, it looks weird

Comment: Maybe you can try setting the [barPadding] to a dynamic value? 
Also, check the official GitHub page, maybe they released a fix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the ngx-charts **barPadding** parameter. 
After setting it to a fixed value, the thickness of the bars remained the same on every request.

To fix the problem add:
`[barPadding]="1"` to the html `<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>` element.